# no java artifacts are generated via jax ws

Tags: java, xsd, jax-ws

I am using JAX-WS 2.1 to generate artifacts from xsd file for Web services.

Here the XSD definition of the problemtic artifact:

```
<xs:simpleType name='Example'>
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Example</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
      <xs:minLength value='0'/>
      <xs:maxLength value='1'/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Jax WS does not generate artifact Example. I do not see class with name Example.

But when I am adding enum to XSD definition then JAX-WS succes generate it:

```
<xs:simpleType name='Example'>
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Example</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
      <xs:minLength value='0'/>
      <xs:maxLength value='1'/>
      <xs:enumeration value='A'/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

If somebody know what the problem please help

Answer (score 0):

`xs:minLength`, `xs:maxLength` cann't be used with `xs:enumeration`. Enumeratio is collection of fixed values, `xs:minLength`, `xs:maxLength` requared for values that is entered in application. So use only enumeration

```
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:enumeration value="A"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="B"/>
     <xsd:enumeration value="C"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But why when I am using only xs:minLength, xs:maxLength then JAX WS does not generate artifact? In original, XSD come only with <xs:minLength value='0'/>       <xs:maxLength value='1'/>. I added enum to check if Jax Ws will generate artifact.

Answer (score 0):

To get a class for your scenario you need a custom binding. [This post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031572/howto-generate-java-enum-from-xml-schema-with-jaxb) shows you the structure of the custom binding file.

One of the things you need to keep in mind is that JAXB by default will generate a class for a complex type, and not for a simple type.